# Oracle IAM/WNA protocol fallback to form-based logon page fails when Microsoft Online Services Sign-In Assistant is installed

Tags: single-sign-on, windows-authentication, sspi

First post here.  Facing a problem where on Windows 10 an Oracle Identity Access Management (IAM) Windows Native Authentication (WNA) protocol fallback to a form-based logon page always fails whenever the Microsoft Online Services Sign-In Assistant (SIA) is installed.  Whenever we remove the SIA, the WNA fallback to a form-based logon page always succeeds.  This error is reproducible 100% of the time. We have not tested on Windows 8 or Windows 7. I've researched it, and there is not much out there to read about the SIA; it does not look to be configurable on the client end.  Really want to avoid changing up code on the IAM WNA side.

Anyone out there seen this before? This is a large enterprise network, using all Windows 10 computers, which has both Oracle IAM running for some applications as well as Microsoft Windows 2008 R2 Active Directory, to which all the Windows 10 computers are joined.  We are also standardized with Office 2016 with all back-end servers supporting Office apps such as Outlook, Lync, etc. in the cloud (Office 365).

Please let me know if I need to show the Oracle IAM/WNA SSO fallback code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Microsoft Online Services Sign-In Assistant is not configurable.  But, if all your computers are running Office 2016 you do not need it anyway and it can be safely uninstalled, which as you said will make the fallback to form-based logon page work.  If you were running Office 2013 you would need it however.  Office 2016 apps such as Outlook and Lync can go direct with ADFS whereas previous versions could not do this.  I don't have a URL reference for you, this is based on my experience.